# Discord embed picture

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord

I have a problem with my discord bot. I want that the picture is being displayed in the embed if that is possible. Currently the image is like bing posted as a own message outside of the embed.

This is my code, could maybe someone help me to figure this out?

```
function fight(interaction, pool, swords) {
    const id = interaction.member.user.id;
    const random_sword = swords[Math.floor(Math.random() * swords.length)];
    const sword_name = random_sword.name;
    const sword_database = random_sword.database;
    const file = new AttachmentBuilder("/home/user/win.jpg");

    pool.query(
        "UPDATE `inv` SET ?? = ?? + 1, `fight` = NOW() WHERE `id` = ? AND (`fight` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) or `fight` is null);",
        [sword_database, sword_database, id],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: "Database error!",
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
            } else {
                if (!(result.changedRows === 0)) {
                    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setTitle("Win!")
                        .setDescription(`Congrats you won!\nYou grabbed a ${sword_name}!`)
                        .setColor("#00ff00")
                        .setAuthor({
                            name: interaction.member.user.username,
                            iconURL: interaction.member.user.avatarURL(),
                        })
                        .setTimestamp();

                    return interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [embed],
                        files: [file],
                    });
                } else {
                    return interaction.reply({
                        content: "You already fought in the last 4 hours!",
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Your embed is lacking the Image attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To showcase the image in the embed, you must specify the attachment path and assign it to the Image attribute within the embed.

I marked the changed rows with //new

```
function fight(interaction, pool, swords) {
    const id = interaction.member.user.id;
    const random_sword = swords[Math.floor(Math.random() * swords.length)];
    const sword_name = random_sword.name;
    const sword_database = random_sword.database;
    const file = new AttachmentBuilder("/home/user/win.jpg");
    const path = "attachment://win.jpg"; //new

    pool.query(
        "UPDATE `inv` SET ?? = ?? + 1, `fight` = NOW() WHERE `id` = ? AND (`fight` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) or `fight` is null);",
        [sword_database, sword_database, id],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: "Database error!",
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
            } else {
                if (!(result.changedRows === 0)) {
                    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setTitle("Win!")
                        .setDescription(`Congrats you won!\nYou grabbed a ${sword_name}!`)
                        .setColor("#00ff00")
                        .setImage(path) //new
                        .setAuthor({
                            name: interaction.member.user.username,
                            iconURL: interaction.member.user.avatarURL(),
                        })
                        .setTimestamp();

                    return interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [embed],
                        files: [file],
                    });
                } else {
                    return interaction.reply({
                        content: "You already fought in the last 4 hours!",
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```